# Is there a way to have notepad++ replace 4 spaces with 2?

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I'm looking through the menu options and don't see any.

I'm thinking about just doing a search for 4 lines and replacing with 2.

For some reason I don't trust this completely.

Comment: Do you mean four **newlines** or four **spaces**?

Comment: If it doesn't work as you expect, you can just not save the file.  Or back it up before you try it. ;)

Comment: I'm just trying to change the style of my code, replacing 4 lines with 2 would change all of the indents.

Comment: Are you sure all your indentation is spaces and not tabs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use Find and Replace (with Regex).  This *exactly* replaces the beginning of a line with 4 spaces with 2 spaces.

Started with:

[image: Notepad++ - Start]

Find and Replace:

[image: Notepad++ - Find and Replace]

Results:

[image: Notepad++ - End]

Comment: yes, I don't believe I have spaces in other places than the beginning of the line, but there is doubt in my mind.

Comment: It only replaces the 4 spaces if they are at the beginning `^`, anywhere else it won't matter.

Comment: If you want to format an entire document(e.g. json) to have only 2 space indent formatting(and it previously had 4 space indent formatting) use:
Find what: \x20\x20\x20\x20
Replace with: \x20\x20\2

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following

1. Set the tabsize to 4 spaces (Settings -> Preferences -> Lanuage Menu/TabSettings)
2. Convert your spaces to tabs (Edit->Blank Operations->Spaces to TAB)
3. Set the tabsize to 2
4. Convert your tabs to spaces (Edit->Blank Operations->TAB to Spaces)

BEWARE: This will mess up  your file, if you currently also use tabs and not only spaces!

Comment: Good "outside the box" thinking.